# How to make React Vite Typescript webpage take up the full height and have a minimum width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a portfolio webpage via React using Vite and Typescript and the webpage is not taking up the height of the content. I have multiple pages with different content that I want to display of varying lengths. What I want is for the  to be the container holding everything in with a navbar "floating above" another div that holds the page content. The  component will have a background color and the pages themselves will also have the same background color. I got the navbar part down but the way I have it app won't extend to take up the browser unless the contents of the pages is the at least the same length as the browser height and if I fix this part with height: 100vh then if the contents of the page has length greater than the browser height then you would see the border of the app in the background:

[image: before]
[image: after]

This is what I want the page to look like:
[image: goal]

What I have above looks great on the outside, but on the inside its an ugly mess I had to use a bunch of break tags to get enough content so that it takes up the browser.

[image: terrible code]

This is a very hacky and terrible solution. What would be the correct way to achieve what I want?

I have tried height: 100% on the  element and also adding it to the html and body tags in the css and it doesn't work. I have tried adding the background color to html and body and it doesn't work .

I have tried using min-height: 100% and also height:100% to both the html, body, and the highest level div in the corresponding .css files and it didn't take up the browser.

Here is the rest of my code on

[image: App code]

Answer (score 2):

posting screenshots is not a super useful way to share code - there are ways to this in the markdown editor when posting a question. Please keep this in mind for future questions.

In any case, when you say height: 100%, you need to ask yourself "what is it 100% of?". Almost always the answer is the parent, so you need to ensure that the thing above it is taking up the screen, ***or*** make the element itself take up the height and width by setting it explicitly.

Setting the following properties on the element you want to make the height and width of the screen will work, but you need to have a play and make sure it doesn't create any unintended consequences about position or sizing of other elements relative to it.

```
.fullscreen-element {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

There are plenty of articles explaining how these properties work. Please also do not use hundreds of break tags. You know it's wrong, so don't even bother!